# Drupal 7 update query is not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

In Drupal 7 custom module, I am updating a record in the database using a form, and I am using the following code to update, but for some reason it is not updating, can anyone tell me why?? I tried like 3 hours to change every possible thing but no luck

function edit_job_form_submit($form, &$form_state){

```
    $id = $form_state['values']['id'];
    $job_title = $form_state['values']['job_title'];
    $description = $form_state['values']['description'];
    $cat_id = $form_state['values']['cat_id'];
    $job_type = $form_state['values']['job_type'];
    $company_id = $form_state['values']['company_id'];
    $description = $form_state['values']['description'];
    $location = $form_state['values']['location'];
    $Salary = $form_state['values']['Salary'];
    $benifits = $form_state['values']['benifits'];
    $Nationality = $form_state['values']['Nationality'];
    $Age = $form_state['values']['Age'];
    $join_date = $form_state['values']['join_date'];
    $date_added = date("y-m-d", time());
    $join_date_mod = gmdate('Y-m-d',strtotime($join_date));

    $num_updated  = db_update('echelon_jobs')
    ->fields(array(
    'job_title' => $job_title,
     'cat_id' => $cat_id,
    'job_type' => $job_type,
    'company_id' => $company_id,
    'location' => $location,
    'Salary' => $Salary,
    'benifits' => $benifits,
    'Nationality' => $Nationality,
    'Age' => $Age,
    'join_date' => $join_date_mod,
    'date_added' => $date_added,
       ))
    ->condition('id', $id)
    ->execute();

   //dpq($num_updated, $name);
    drupal_set_message(t('Vacancy Updated Successfully..  '));
```

}

Comment: just to be clear - the submit function is being called, right? You are getting the 'Vacancy update successfully' message, you're just not seeing the changes in the DB?
And you have checked the drupal and php logs and there are no errors - perhaps a mismatch with your data and the db schema?

Answer (score 2):

May be you condition is not right . may be your variable id has null value or some value which does not exist in the table.

Answer (score 1):

1. check what db_update() returns
2. turn on error reporting in drupal/mysql logging and check if there are any errors